# Google Cloud DNS - Web UI View Records

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Hello Stackoverflow,

i found an very irritating issue using the google cloud dns web ui. We have created over 3k on records in the service for one zone. however the rendering of the page takes now quite some time but i can live with that. however not all records are listed. lets say i only get the records until the letter L but not the rest. I can not see a search button to narrow down my object of interest. What could be my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud DNS web ui presently doesn't have a Search or Filter capability. However, you could use the Cloud DNS APIs 
https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/managedZones/list

and leverage the nextPageToken param to navigate the list of zones.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud DNS launched Filter ability in the UI that will help your case.

This is a filter textbox, where you need to enter your complete zone information. there isn't partial zone match or auto-suggest at this time